# Powershell: Get content of a folder, delete specific files, verify if the files were deleted/exist

Tags: powershell

All the work must be logged, I am trying to list the content of folder, delete certain files, in my example there are 3 files inside the folder I want to deleted. then list each file to see if the file exists (was not deleted) or does not exists (got deleted).

This is what I could do so far:

```
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"; 
    $mindump = gci c:\test1 -recurse -Include Minidump*.dmp 
    remove-item $mindump -force -whatif
```

When I want to verify which files were deleted or not:

```
    $mindump | % { $a =$_; test-path $_ | where {$_ -eq $True} | %{ write-host $a File still exists or a new file with the same name was created}}
```

It works for finding out if the file still exists, but if I try something like:

```
    $mindump | % { $a =$_; test-path $_ | where {$_ -eq $True} | %{ write-host $a File still exists or a new file with the same name was created} | % else { write-host $a File was deleted/does not exists} }
```

It doesn't work at all. What other things could I do?

Comment: Why are you doing the extra work of assigning `$_` (`$PSItem`) to a variable?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 You are correct, I forgot to remove that, I left the $a = $_ as I was doing some other testings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple syntax error. You cannot use `else` as a response to a `ForEach-Object` loop, you would need to use an `If` statement.

```
$mindump | % { 
    $a =$_
    If(test-path $_){ 
        write-host $a File still exists or a new file with the same name was created
    } else { 
        write-host $a File was deleted/does not exists
    } 
}
```

Comment: I found the exact same conclusion some seconds before reading the response. Thanks!